# Bootstrap 4 theme-color("primary") function returns bootstrap default primary color rather than overriden primary color

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4

In custom.scss, modify theme-colors map

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

$theme-colors: ( 
    "primary": #3275B3, 
    "secondary": #004f93
);
```

In main.scss, overrides imported before bootstrap

```
@import "./custom.scss"; //import bootstrap overrides
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"; //import bootstrap
```

I have a navbar with .bg-primary and button .btn-primary that get rendered correctly, but it appears that bootstrap attributes set with bootstraps theme-colors() function aren't being set properly. They still use bootstraps default primary color, rather than my overridden primary color.

Example in bootstrap's _variables.scss file:

```
$component-active-bg: theme-color("primary") !default;
```

Tried setting $component-active-bg in my custom.scss and that didn't work either...

How do you properly override bootstrap 4's primary color?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
$theme-colors: ( 
    "primary": #3275B3, 
    "secondary": #004f93
);
```

try with

```
$primary:       #3275B3;
$secondary:     #004f93;
```

Although both version work well for me.

## Edit:

Found the reason why it does not work.
In your *custom.scss* you are importing bootstrap with `@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`

Then you customize theme colors

And in your *main.scss* you import the *custom.scss* and then importing bootstrap again. And thus overriding $theme-colors again with the default values from bootstrap.

Comment: Setting $primary and $secondary in my custom.scss does not work as expected. Primary and secondary are the bootstrap defaults, but other overrides, like $font-size-base are applied.

If I remove the import to bootstrap from my main.scss, no overrides are applied. 

I am following their documentation on [Theming](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/) and [Webpack](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/)...

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug CRA Tests",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts",
      "args": ["test", "--runInBand", "--no-cache", "--watchAll=false"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "env": { "CI": "true" },
      "disableOptimisticBPs": true
    }
  ]
}
```